# Python: Performance test, ensuring cleanup

Tags: python

I am executing some performance tests on a messaging framework within python, and I am trying to make sure that the code is properly cleaning up after itself.

Is there a way to monitor the current number of threads owned by the process?  Is there a better way to tell if I am leaking threads?

---

Just to make sure I clarify what I am looking for  as an answer.  I need a script and or program that can monitor the number of threads that a process has alive.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This function will tell you how many threads are currently alive: [`threading.activeCount()`](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#threading.activeCount). You can also enumerate those threads using the [`threading.enumerate()`](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#threading.enumerate) function.

Comment: interesting, I will try this out now.

Comment: It would be nice to give more of a detailed answer but I was able to leverage this.

Comment: Glad this was helpful for you. I've added in a little more detail to my answer, though it seems pretty straightforward. As an infrequent thread user myself, it might be helpful to others if you shared your eventual solution.

Answer (score 5):

Use [python profiler](http://docs.python.org/library/profile.html) to generate stats files,
then use [gprof2dot](http://code.google.com/p/jrfonseca/wiki/Gprof2Dot) to generate graph

```
gprof2dot -f pstats output.pstats | dot -Tpng -o output.png
```

you can use other stats viewers provided for python